# Rich Notification is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**I'm currently working a chrome extension that will notify if the getElementId is not in the page.. and unfortunately the rich notification is not showing in contennt script. Should I use Message Passing for this?**

**load.js**

```
con = document.getElementById('content');

if (con !=null){

     var options = {

    type:"basic",
    title:"Error",
    message:"Error",
    iconUrl:"logo1.png"
}

chrome.notifications.create(options, callback);

function callback()
{

    console.log('yey');
}

}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "CRM Online Chrome Extension",
    "description": "License authentication key for the clients.",
    "version": "1.0",

 "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"




        ],
        "persistent": true
    },


      "content_scripts":[
{


    "matches":[ "*://*/*",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "js":["payload.js","load.js"]

}


    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Sample",
        "default_icon": "logo1.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"

    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*",
        "*://*/*"






    ]


    // "options_page": "option.html"
}
```

Comment: `chrome.notification` API is not accessible by content scripts. You should pass a message to the background page which in turn will call the `chrome.notification` function.

Comment: i get your idea, but i don't know how to do it. because this the first that i will create an extension so i don't know how to syntax it. is it okay to you if you give an example syntax?

Comment: @dionell, This question contains code that is very similar to the code contained in [this question asked 5 hours earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41009764/3773011).  Is this a group project? A school assignment?

Comment: @dionell, At a minimum, please [look at the code formatting edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41009764/revisions) which were made to that question with by two different high reputation users. Those edits were done to make the question easier to read by users here. Please make similar code formatting edits to your code in this question. We do not care about maintaining any particular code formatting conventions. We do care about consistently using the same conventions throughout your code (or at least within related code blocks, because doing so makes it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from your content script to the background page and this latter can create the notification upon the reception of the message.

For example:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
    if (message.value == "contentPresent"){  //if the message received is the one we sent from our content script
        chrome.notifications.create({  //create notificacion
            type:"basic",
            title:"Error",
            message:"Error",
            iconUrl:"logo1.png"
        }, function(){
              console.log("yey");
        });
   }
});
```

**content.js**

```
if (document.getElementById("content")) {  //if the element with id "content" is found...
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({value:"contentPresent"});   //send a message to the background script
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping. it works, but i want to know or learn more about it so can you explain it to me?

Comment: @dionell if the solution worked then i think u shud accept his answer, regarding how it works- it's a long story https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: If the content script detects the element with id "content", it [sends a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) to the background script. When the background script receives the message from the content script, it creates the notification.